# Loop with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the below code:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two']

for (index in arr) {
  console.log('outside promise:', arr[index])

  myPromise().then(function(response) {
    console.log('inside promise:', arr[index])
  })
}
```

My output:

```
// outside promise: one
// outside promise: two
// inside promise: one
// inside promise: one
```

Why the hack the console output inside the promise doesn't loop trough values?

Comment: Could you be more clear, I don't really understand what your stating the issue is?

Comment: Where is `myPromise` defined? What is expected result?

Comment: inside your loop try var x = arr[index]; then console.log(x) inside the promise

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130019/how-to-chain-promises-in-for-loop-in-vanilla-javascript

Comment: I'm surprised at your claimed output - it **should** output `inside promise: two` twice not `inside promise: one` twice - the issue is to do with asynchronicity - by the time BOTH `.then`s get called, index is 1 - therefore arr[1] will be logged

Comment: @PenAndPapers - that would make zero difference

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) And [don't forget to declare your `var`iables!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

As `@Jaromanda X` stated in the comment, correct output will be:

```
// outside promise: one
// outside promise: two
// inside promise: TWO
// inside promise: TWO
```

Since promises will be resolved when index already will be `1`, not 0. If you getting different results in console, it can be `stdout` concurrency issues. Try to add results to the array, and then output it;

```
const arr = ['one', 'two'];
let results = [];

for (index in arr) {
  results.push(`outside promise: ${arr[index]}`)

  myPromise().then(function(response) {
      results.push(`inside promise: ${arr[index]}`)
  })
}

console.dir(results);
```

Comment: There is no difference wether you log the value or push it to an Array (in terms of timing). The problem is the same.

Comment: @Thomas which problem?

Comment: that the `array[index]` inside the closure will be resolved AFTER the loop has FINISHED iterating. And that for all iterations with the same index, the last one.

Comment: It is not a problem. It is expected behavior. Problem is, that user demonstrates unexpected behavior - his output from promise `one, one`, not `two, two`